# How to get geolocation using or passing address in Apex?

Tags: apex

How to get geolocation from address using apex like in an object on creation or updation of an address in a record i want to update the geolocation field in that record

Comment: did you check this https://blog.internetcreations.com/2012/09/creating-a-geolocation-trigger-in-salesforce-winter-13/#.WIg1jdIrLDd

Comment: Is the address related to accounts, contacts, or leads?